# Python 3: Is there a better way to find and replace certain items in a text file?

Tags: python, replace, split

I have thousands of text files with two lines of text in each file, see the attached image.
[image]
I don't need to make any changes to the first line. I need to find and replace some of the items in the 2nd line and then write the file in the **exact same format (position of each line and item)** as the original file. For example, to change '50.0' located at the end of the second line to '90.0', I did the following.

```
    import 0s, glob
    folder path = "./data/"
    
    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.ops')):
        with open(filename,'r+') as f:
           existing_lines = f.read().splitlines()
           existing_lines[1]='  1  1     2011   10    1             80.0   50.0   50.0   20.0   
 20.0   90.0'
        with open(filename,'r+') as f:
           f.write ('\n'.join(existing_lines))
```

Is there a robust way of solving this problem?

Alternative:

```
import os,glob
import re
folder_path = "./data/"

def listToString(s): 
    empty_str = " " 
    return (empty_str.join(s))
         
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.ops')):
    with open(filename,'r+') as f:
        list_of_lists = [(re.split(r'(\s+)', (line.strip()))) for line in f]
        list1 = list_of_lists[0]
        list2 = list_of_lists[1]
        list2[-1]= '90.0'
        f.truncate(0)
    
    with open(filename,'r+') as f:
        f.write (listToString(list1)+'\n')
        f.write (listToString(list2))
```

Comment: Looks like some civil engineering data or something? First I would say the format is terrible and would suggest turning the “thousands of files” into a database but you probably have no control over that, in which case I would recommend building an object that takes a file path as an argument, reads and parses it then assigns the values to corresponding properties allowing for easy up dates then has a function to create a new file based on the updated values.

Comment: Are the items tab-separated?

Comment: not tab separated. These are fixed files separated by space.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: How do you know what changes to make?  You could use regex, but in your example, how do you know to change the last 50.0 but not the 2 earlier 50.0 values?  If you are looking for certain lines of text to swap with other lines of text, you could create a dictionary or Pandas dataframe, then open each file and check whether the file's 2nd line matches an entry you want to change.

Comment: I found regex tricky to implement in my case. Alternatively, I attempted to use list() and truncate() -- see the 2nd code in the original post!. Everything seemed to work fine; the only problem was that I was not able to write the file in the same format as the original file. For example, in the output file, the leading spaces in both lines got removed. The model I am using is sensitive to the position of each word/item.

Answer (score 0):

The best solotion to find some text patten is use regural expression.

**Regular Expression Example:**

```
import re
line = '  1  1     2011   10    1             80.0   50.0   50.0   20.0   20.0   90.0'
if re.search('( +\d+){5}( +\d+.\d+){6}', line):
    print("This line match to searching pattern")
else:
    print("This line dont mach to pattern")
```

When you find lines that intrest you can eazy manipulate with them

Ps. If this don't work propably you must replace all spaces inside reqluar expresson `'( *\d+){5}( +\d+.\d+){6}'` to `\t` (this is tabaulator sign)

**Your case:**

```
import re, os

import 0s, glob
path = "./data/"

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.ops')):
    edited_lines = ''
    with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if re.search('( *\d+){5}( +\d+.\d+){6}', line):
                # Here you can modify numeric data whatever you want
            else:
                edited_lines += line
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(edited_lines)
```

Idk what else you want to do but now code look much cleaner ;)

Comment: If you wait i will try write maching expresson for you

Comment: Low Quality answer.

Comment: Tbh i want to wirte this like a comment but unfortunately i don't have enough reputation :<